# When Would be a Good Time To Get Together In PMSE Chat To Discuss the Site?

Tags: discussion, chat

Is there is a time that would work for a get-together in the PMSE chat room to discuss the site and bounce around ideas?

What time(s) would work best to discuss the site? Could this be a regular thing that we do? Could multiple times work so we get everyone involved?

**UPDATE:** *Our first PMSE Community Moderation Chat is scheduled for 1:00 AM GMT on June 9th, 2012. See [the chat schedule page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/380/project-management?tab=schedule) to register and for more details. I also think it will convert the time to your timezone :)*

Possible agenda:

- [What kinds of edits can we make to improve questions?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/what-kinds-of-edits-can-we-make-to-improve-questions)
- [Should I have migrated this question from Programmers SE?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/313/34)
- Questions about: [A guide to moderating PMSE as a member of the community](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/34)

Comment: I look forward to coordinating something.

Comment: I deleted my analysis of the 5 questions I picked. 2k users (users with access to moderator tools on beta sites) can still see them. I may unearth them later, but taking baby steps can go a long way to making a lot of questions [*look* like they conform to SE standards](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/314/what-kinds-of-edits-can-we-make-to-improve-questions). If our users with [edit] privileges help out, we can make the questions look a lot better for the review. (I know better is subjective here. They're not all bad questions, they just need some TLC).

Comment: You might try a Chat event. Never used one myself though

Comment: @BenBrocka - Great idea. I'll set one of those up.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hanging out in our dusty, empty chat room lately and could chat a bit during my lunch break if anyone stops by. I usually do lunch at about 7pm GMT / 12pm PDT.

Most of our users tend to be more active during the week, but I honestly prefer weekends. Evening hours work as well, with evenings for me occurring roughly at  GMT -7, but weekday nights might be kinda tough for people in other parts of the world.

I was thinking that varying the times a bit could help get everyone involved.

**UPDATE: Here is the transcript from the first chat:**

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4876019#4876019