# Should I have migrated this question from Programmers SE?

Tags: discussion, site-topic, migration

[How can I ensure our project gets developed successfully, without having any project management experience?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/how-can-i-ensure-our-project-gets-developed-successfully-without-having-any-pro)

A mod on Programmers SE asked me if this question was on-topic on PMSE. After reading it, I said to send it over.

Was this the right call? What are the merits of this question that make it on-topic? What makes it constructive/not constructive? Should it be closed or left opened?

What improvements could be made to it to make it a great Q&A question?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I flagged it at Programmers SE with a note that I bet it would be a better fit for PM SE.  However, I think that given the OP's starting point (zero), answers from Programmers would've been adequate -- they would certainly get the job done.

But for a likely richer PM perspective, PM SE would  give the OP a better foundation once past the initial "What the heck DO I DO?" aspects that prompted the question in the first place.

While the OP could've provided more information about the specifics of the project, I don't think that would really change any of the answers; the answers the OP has gotten *could* (should?) prompt more (separate) questions.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot and confirms a lot of what I was thinking. So, SE plans to do a site review of PMSE soon, and I was thinking that we should locate questions that should have been closed and really focus on editing them as much as we can to make them look on topic. Not only would it be a step in the right direction, but it's an idea I think most people here would support, and it would give us more practice for the NARQ and not constructive questions that hit the site. [What are your thoughts on community editing of questions](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/314/34)?

Comment: @jmort253 Well, I upvoted your answer. :)  I should try to get 197 more rep so I can help out more...

Comment: Yes, you're very close to hitting 1000. Still, keep in mind that suggested edits go into a review queue, so anything you edit is still visible to anyone with 1000 rep. Plus, prior to hitting 1000, you get 2 rep points per approved edit ;)

Comment: Oh, I know!  But as a mod I know how lengthy that review queue can get sometimes... :)

Comment: The queue here is pretty empty. 3 to 4 has been the max we've seen in a day.